# IE 11 and mozila the checkboxes dont work

Tags: html, css

```
<input class="regular-checkbox ucheckbox" type="checkbox">
```

[this is a example for working box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K6rIR.png)

```
<input name="atnc" class="regular-checkbox" id="addtnchchk" type="checkbox">
```

[this is a example for not working box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BzW1a.png)

```
    .regular-checkbox{
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  background-color: white;
  border:1px solid #cbd6e2;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  position: relative;
}

.regular-checkbox:active, .regular-checkbox:focus{
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 7px #00b0f0;
    border:1px solid #00b0f0;
}

.regular-checkbox:checked {
  background-color: #00b0f0;
  border:1px solid #00b0f0;
  color: white;
}
.regular-checkbox:focus{
  outline:0 !important;
  outline-offset: 0 !important;
}
.regular-checkbox:checked:after {
  font:normal normal normal 14px/1 FontAwesome;
  content: '\f00c';
  font-size: 15px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 3px;
  left: 2px;
  color: white;
}
```

why all the checkboxes on site works but this one didnt work same issue on mozila too ??  chrome work fine all!

Comment: Does FF have any errors in the console?

Comment: What does "not working" mean in your case?

Comment: i click on box and it didnt check

Comment: which FF version are you using?

Comment: HTML1524: Invalid HTML5 DOCTYPE. Consider using the interoperable form "<!DOCTYPE html>". this one can be the problem?? FROM IE...  unreachable code after return statement
[Learn More] this one from FF

Comment: are you using the ID `addtnchchk` multiple times in your doc?

Comment: the second error indicates a WARNING something wrong with some JS does it give a line number to help you see what it is? there appears to be some code after the return statement of a function that is not reached or a semicolon. Neither of which shoul daffect the checkbox

Comment: no just once in page just check

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys I just found the error!!!  All my working checkboxes were in `<span></span>` and others which didn't work were in `<button></button>`.

The IE and FF browsers consider it like click on button not on checkbox. But works fine on  Chrome ..!!! Thank you for time and for attention!